# Data not sent using jquery .ajax() to a Django view

Tags: django, jquery, django-views

I am trying to create a single ajax call. The ajax call is sent to server but the data then I am sending is not available in the request object in the view. When I print `request.post`, it gives `<QueryDict: {}>`. No data is being sent to the server. I know that the browser is sending the data since I can view it in the request payload in chrome.

**script:**

```
$("#chatform").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //serialText = $(this).serialize();
    var userText = $("#usertext").val();
    var xmlRequest = $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/sendmessage/",
            data: {'tosend': userText},

            //dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data){
                appendMessageSent(data.messagesent);
            }
    });
});
```

**view.py:**

```
def send_message(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "The hell with the world"

        print request.POST
        json = simplejson.dumps(
            {'messagesent' : request.POST['tosend']+"This is how we do it"}
        )
        return HttpResponse(json, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

**html**

```
<form id="chatform" action="" method="POST" >
        <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='8idtqZb4Ovy6eshUtrAiYwtUBboW0PpZ' />
        <input type="text" name="chatarea" id="usertext"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

I get an error saying that key `tosend` is not found in `request.post` dict.

`MultiValueDictKeyError: "Key 'tosend' not found in <QueryDict: {}>`

Can any one tell me why the data is not being sent to the server and/or why I can't access it in my view?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make form data appear in `request.POST`, use `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`.

If you use `application/json`, you have to parse the raw data yourself (`request.raw_post_data` in django <1.4, `request.body` in django >=1.4):

```
def send_message(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        message = "The hell with the world"

        data = json.loads(request.body)
        result = json.dumps({'messagesent' : data['tosend'] + "This is how we do it"})
        return HttpResponse(result, mimetype='application/javascript')
```

Comment: That sounds good but I am getting the following error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'json' referenced before assignment`. I am doing `import json` in the file.

Comment: Is the there an advantage of using  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" over application/json?

Comment: Oops, sorry, I replaced simplejson with json and forgot there already was a variable named json. Fixed.

Comment: In your case the only advantage is that you don't have to parse anything yourself.

Comment: It seems that the default contentType is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" in jQuery (1.7) so all I had to do was to remove contentType: "application/json" from the AJAX call to get it working.